# On an inequality involving the Lambert $W$ function and the sum of divisors function

Tags: nt.number-theory, analytic-number-theory, inequalities, special-functions, arithmetic-functions

Let $W(n)$ be the principal/main branch of the Lambert $W$ function (this is the [*Wikipedia*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function) related to this special function). I was inspired in Robin equivalence to the Riemann hypothesis (see [1]) and [2] to state the following conjecture. Also we denote the sum of divisors function $\sum_{1\leq d\mid n}d$ as $\sigma(n)$, $\exp(1)=e$ is the number $e$ and $\gamma$ denotes the Euler-Mascheronin constant. I believe that the following conjecture isn't in the literature.

**Conjecture.** *For each integer $n>5040$ one has that the inequality
$$\sigma(n)<e^{\gamma}W(en)e^{W(n)}\log(W(n))\tag{1}$$
holds.*

My computational evidence (for the statement of previous conjecture) is up to $10^5$. My motivation to rewrite the RHS of Robin equivalence to the Riemann hypothesis in terms of the Lambert $W$ function is [2], and that the Lambert $W$ function is a function with a great mathematical content and this function is related to applications in physics, and finally to explore the difference between the RHS of Robin inequality and the RHS of (1).

> **Question.** Is it possible to prove or refute previous **Conjecture**? I'm asking if you can to find an integer $n_0$ such that the inequality $(1)$ holds for all $n>n_0$ or a counterexample for previous conjecture. **Many thanks.**

I'm asking this because maybe it is possible to provide a reasoning, heuristic  or computation about it. Then from this, I should accept an answer.

**Update:** I add an optional question, I hope that my genuine post has enough mathematical content, so I add as an optional question if it is possible to state the Riemann hypothesis in terms of the Lambert $W$ function: involving the Lambert $W$ function in an asymptotic identity or inequality and the arithmetic function that you think that is more suitable in your equivalent formulation of the Riemann hypothesis (I evoke that it is possible, but in any case, my secondary question is optional).

> **Question (Optional).**  Is it possible to state an equivalent formulation of the Riemann hypothesis involving the Lambert $W$ function in an asymptotic identity or inequality and, additionally/maybe, also involving any suitable arithmetic function? **Many thanks.**

My belief is that should be possible to state an equivalent form of Riemann hypothesis in terms of particular values of a suitable arithmetic function and the Lambert $W$ function.

### References:

[1] Guy Robin, *Grandes Valeurs de la fonction somme des diviseurs et hypothèse de Riemann*, J. Math. Pures Appl. 63, 187-213, (1984).

[2] Matt Visser, *[Primes and the Lambert $W$ function](https://arxiv.org/abs/1311.2324)*, Cornell University Library (November 2013).

Comment: Please, in case that you can to find a counterexample for the statement of the **Conjecture**, I would appreciate a discussion, in your answer, about whether there are arbitrarily large counterexamples.

Comment: Since your motivation is in a document (a thesis?) that does not seem easily accessible to other people, maybe you should include some of it in the question.

Comment: Yes, I'm sorry, but I'm just was motivated by the asymptotics in the paper  @LSpice I know it as the reference **arXiv:1311.2324v2** on arXiv  by professor Matt Visser, *Primes and the Lambert $W$ function*, Cornell University Library (November 2013). Many thanks for your attention.

Comment: If you have a publically available reference, then you should give that in the question!  I have edited accordingly.

Comment: It seems that for $n>10000$, $n \log{\log{n}}<W(en)e^{W(n)}\log{(W(n))}$, so any counterexample to your conjecture would imply the Riemann hypothesis is false, by [Robin's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divisor_function#Growth_rate).

Comment: Many thanks and my apologies to previous professor in commments. About your first inequality, do you think that it is possible to prove it @LeechLattice ? If you can add what work can be done feel free to add it as an answer, since I got my inequality by comparison with RHS of Robin inequality by trial and error. Many thanks also for you.

Comment: For the optional question I add the following comment, with the idea that can be inspiring: **a link between** the asymptotic of the imaginary part $\gamma_n$ of the $n$-th non-trivial zero of the Riemann zeta function $\rho_n$ (ordered in ascending order with $\Im \rho_n>0$) **and** the Lambert $W$ function was posted in one of the answers of the post *Asymptotics for zeta zeros?* in Math Stack Exchange (Sep 7 '2014), the identificator of the question is **921987** that you can to type in the browser of MSE